# Bluebird Promise.map child_process.execFile - read output from callback

Tags: promise, bluebird

I am brand new to [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) and trying to instantiate multiple `child_process.execFile`'s by using `Promise.map` and read/combine all of their `stdout` at completion. Right now, in order to execute one `execFile` and read the `error`, `stdout`, and `stderr` I do it like this:

```
child_process.execFile("node", [ script, 1 ], function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    ...
});
```

I can achieve this same thing with this block of code here

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
execFile = Promise.promisify(execFile);
var print = "print.js";

execFile("node", [ script, 1 ]).then(
function (stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
},
function (stderr) {
    console.log(stderr);
});
```

When I attempt to do this using bluebird and `map`, I am modeling it, more or less, around [this](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) example. I want to take the example above and be able to call it with multiple command line arguments, like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Promise.map(arr, function(i) {
    return execFile("node", [ script, 1 ])
}).then(
function (array_of_all_stdout) {
    console.log(array_of_all_stdout);
},
function (array_of_all_stderr) {
    console.log(array_of_all_stderr);
});
```

I feel like I am so close, I just cannot find a way to read the returned values with `map`. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have a typo `function (array_of_all_stdout) { console.log(stdout); },`

Comment: And what you have (after the typo fix) doesn't work still?